# Setting up Ganglia on spark running on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, ganglia

I am trying to set up ganglia on ec2 servers, but can't seem to recevie info from any other host than my master.
The master meterics are showing fine, but I have 4 more nodes that aren't listed in the web interface.
My question is - could it be that because I'm using unicast I can only see the master node, and that it's aggregating all of the other nodes data?

I have ran both gmetad and gmond in the foreground, and saw that the node and the master are communicating with each other, but still can't see the node in the web UI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you running? I had this issue at some point but it went away when I upgraded to a newer version of Spark.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Spark version is 1.4.1.
Are you running Ganglia on EC2? Do you see 1 node per EC2 instance or only one node?

Comment: I saw only one node in Ganglia, while the Spark UI showed all my executors. But as mentioned, I haven't seen the problem since upgrading to 1.4.x...

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks, but it seems like my problems are coming from somewhere else. Do you know what is the location where ganglia saves its data? (It might help understand whether data is not gathered or simply doesn't reach the UI)